# Active Class is not working after page navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created some list items of anchor list for menu in Master Page. By default only one is active. After clicking on other items, active class is assign to them. But the problem comes after page navigation. Default class becomes active again.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Office.aspx">Office</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Market.aspx">Market</a></li>
            </ul>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlNavigation" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        ---------CONTENT PAGE HOLDER------------
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And My jQuery in master page is like following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: When you navigate away from the current page, you are on a new page. The new page has no clue about the state of the original page.

Comment: Thank you @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I understand this problem. Can you tell me some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect with window.location, it will reload the page so you loose the active class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
// You can add an id to your a tags and set:
            var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?id=' + $(this).attr('id');
            window.location.replace(url);
        });
    });
```

then:

```
//when document is ready, it reads the id on the url if there's some
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(var id = getUrlParameter('id')) $(id).addClass('active');
});

// this will get URL params:

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page url and set the class on the corresponding menu. There are better ways to do this, but this answer is easy to understand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...your existing code...
    var page = document.location;
    if(page.indexOf("Office") > -1) {
       $('#Office').addClass('active');
    }
    .... etc ...
});
```

New mark-up

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="Home" href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="Office" href="../Office.aspx">Office</a></li>
    <li><a id="Market" href="../Market.aspx">Market</a></li>
</ul>
```